# Read .las (LiDAR data) in iOS

Tags: ios, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am making an app render the cloud points on different layer. For now I am consuming the data as .txt file converted from .las file. My question is: is there a way or lib to directly consume the .las format on iOS device? I searched about the libLAS (http://www.liblas.org/) but don't think it will work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try LASlib of LAStools. It compiles without dependencies and also reads compressed LAS aka LAZ.

http://github.com/LAStools/LAStools/tree/master/LASlib

Comment: Martin, you mean include LASlib in xcode for iOS build?